# Вывод массива: цикл foreach

Tags: массивы, php, циклы

Есть 2 массива:

```
$users = array(1,2,3,4,5); //Все Пользователи
$friends = array(2,3); //Мои Друзья
```

Как через цикл `foreach` сравнить первый массив (пользователи) со вторым массивом (друзья) и вывести на экран только тех пользователей, которых нет во втором массиве (друзья)?
Помогите, пожалуйста!)

Answer (score 2):

Для таких вещей рациональнее использовать функцию для вычисления расхождения массивов [array_diff()](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php).

Посмотрите [ссылку](http://ideone.com/rd8zkG).

```
$users = array(1,2,3,4,5);

$friends = array(2,3);

$result = array_diff($users, $friends);

print_r($result);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Comment: а если мне будет нужно вывести всех пользователей с первого массива с меткой Добавить, тоесть сравнить, если в 2-м масииве есть пользователь, то мы метку не ставим! Например, сравнили массивы, вывод:
1 - Добавить
2 - Добавлен
3 - Добавлен
4 - Добавить
5 - Добавить

Тоесть (2,3) я уже добавил! как решить эту задачу?

Comment: @amf1k, я написал правильное решение той задачи, что Вы поставили. Дополнительных условий не было. Извините, если что не так.

Comment: Вот полный код:
$users = array(
   1=>array('id'=>1, 'login'=>'Лена'),
   2=>array('id'=>2, 'login'=>'Света'), 
   3=>array('id'=>3, 'login'=>'Ксюша'), 
   4=>array('id'=>4, 'login'=>'Юля'), 
   5=>array('id'=>5, 'login'=>'Даша')
);
$friends = array(
   1=>array('addressee'=>2),
   2=>array('addressee'=>3)
);
foreach($users as $value) {
   foreach($friends as $value2) {
      if($value['id'] == $value2['addressee']) {
         $key = 'Friend';
      }
      else {
         $key = 'No Friend';
      }
      echo $value['login'].' - '. $key.'<br/>';
   }
}
все ок,только цикл выводит инфу дважды

Comment: @amf1k, Вам не кажется, что данные немного отличаются от приведенных в вопросе?

Comment: ключевое слово *немного*(это был простой вопрос), суть не меняется)

Comment: @amf1k, это вы так думаете

Comment: может проще было выводить это все через цикл *do while* ???

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($users as $key => &$user) {
    foreach ($friends as $friend) {
        $id = reset($friend);
        if ($id == $user['id']) {
            $user['isFriend'] = true;
            break 2;
        }
    }
    $user['isFriend'] = false;
}
```

Comment: Что-то не получается вывести, на выходе получаю false везде(

Comment: @amf1k, обновил, но не тестировал.

Comment: Вы, как с опытом, помогите решить эту задачу, где я ошибся, как можно реализовать эту задачу проще?